# How can I perform a scalar product on a matrix of pairs?

Tags: j

I have a matrix `M`containing pairs (i.e. arrays of size 2). Given a pair `p`, how can I get a 2D matrix `M'`containing the result of the scalar product of `p` and each element of `M`?

```
    (0, 0) (0, 1)                             8 5
M = (1, 0) (1, 1)       p = (2, 2)       M' = 5 2
    (2, 0) (2, 1)                             4 1
```

`M` and `p` are defined :

```
M =. 3 2 2 $ 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 2 0 2 1
p =. 2 2
```

I have an implementation of scalar product in J :

```
sp =. +/ @: *: @: -
```

It works on pairs :

```
    0 0 sp p
8
    0 1 sp p
5
```

But not on the full matrix, because of bad length :

```
    p sp M
|length error: sp
|   p     sp M
```

How should I deal with that ? This is probably easy for J geniuses, but I'm just a poor newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
p sp"1 M
 8 5
 5 2
 4 1
```

You want `sp` here to read first-rank cells of M:

```
<"1 M
┌───┬───┐
│0 0│0 1│
├───┼───┤
│1 0│1 1│
├───┼───┤
│2 0│2 1│
└───┴───┘
```

so `sp"1` will work on each cell (`p sp 0 0`, `p sp 0 1`, etc). `sp` (infinite rank) tries to apply sp once for the whole matrix M.

Likewise `sp"2` will apply `sp` on second-rank cells of M:

```
<"2 M
 ┌───┬───┬───┐
 │0 0│1 0│2 0│
 │0 1│1 1│2 1│
 └───┴───┴───┘
```

so

```
p sp"2 M
 8 5
 2 5
 0 5
```

(the pairs: `p sp 2 2 $ 0 0 0 1`, `p sp 2 2 $ 1 0 1 1` and `p sp 2 2 $ 2 0 2 1`)